# Mouse Enter/Leave Polyfill for Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent

Is there a polyfill for the IE events `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` (or a conversion of the jQuery events) so it can be bound to raw JS events?

I.E. I is there a cross browser way to do this:

```
node.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    ...
});

node.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    ...
});
```

I know it should be possible custom events using:

```
var event = new Event('mouseenter');
node.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) { ... });
node.dispatchEvent(event);
etc
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, seems I figured out how to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/HXwJH/5/

```
node.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {    
    if (!event.relatedTarget || (event.relatedTarget !== this && !(this.compareDocumentPosition(event.relatedTarget) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY))) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseenter'));
    }
});

node.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {    
    if (!event.relatedTarget || (event.relatedTarget !== this && !(this.compareDocumentPosition(event.relatedTarget) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY))) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseleave'));
    }
});
```